# Moment.js convert x minutes to y hours z minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-formatting

So I have a number, for instance `90`. what I want to do is convert it to `"1 hr 30 mins"`. I have tried this:

```js
moment.utc(
    moment.duration(90, "minutes")
    .asMilliseconds()
).format("h:mm")
```

This returns `1:30`.

If it do this,

```js
moment.utc(
    moment.duration(90, "minutes")
    .asMilliseconds()
).format("h [hour] mm [minutes]")
```

, then I get `1 hour 30 minutes`.

This is great, but if I plug in 180, then I get `3 hour 00 minutes`, but it should be `3 hours`. The 00 minutes should be omitted, and *hour* should be *hours* when the number of hours is greater than 1. The same goes for minutes.

Is this possible with moment.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write a bit of custom code to solve the problem, like this:

```js
const time1 = moment.utc(
  moment.duration(180, "minutes")
  .asMilliseconds()
)

const time2 = moment.utc(
  moment.duration(90, "minutes")
  .asMilliseconds()
)

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = time.minutes();
  const hours = time.hours();
  const hourFormatStr = hours === 1 ? 'hour' : 'hours';
  const minuteFormatStr = minutes === 1 ? 'minute' : 'minutes';
  if (!time.minutes()) {
    return time.format(`h [${hourFormatStr}]`);
  }
  return time.format(`h [${hourFormatStr}] mm [${minuteFormatStr}]`);
}

console.log(formatTime(time1));
console.log(formatTime(time2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Also, I found [this library](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format), which seems to do the job you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible with momemt js.

We have to construct the format dynamically based on the hour and minute value we get. Please check the code below.

```
input=180;

hour=Math.floor(input/60);
min=input%60;
format = "";
//console.log(hour);
//console.log(min);
if (hour>1 && min>1)
    format = "h [hours] mm [minutes]";
else if (hour>1 && min==1)
    format = "h [hours] mm [minute]";
else if (hour>1 && min==0)
    format = "h [hours]";
else if( hour==0 && min>1)
    format = "m [minutes]";
else if (hour==0 && min<=1)
    format = "mm [minute]";
else
    format="";
//console.log(format);

moment.utc(
    moment.duration(input, "minutes")
    .asMilliseconds()
).format(format)
```